# Zigzag pattern on differential traces

Tags: pcb-design, altium, differential

Does anyone know what this pattern means in Altium Designer? If it is related to a warning, how do I get rid of it?

[image: Screenshot of zigzag-like pattern on differential traces]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did a DRC or have automatic DRC turned on, right click on the trace and goto to violations, that will tell you the rule that is being violated.

If there is no violation, another thing that you could have turned on is the highlighting in the PCB panel.